# AngularJs and jQueryUi

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using both the angularJs and jQueryUI. But only one of them is working at a time, it has a first come first serve basis.
I am baiscaly using accordian function of jqueryUi, but it throws error when it is combined with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [angular directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). They are the part of angular which takes care of DOM manipulation. There are plenty of guides around to help you get started.